# jscript if for global variable

Tags: javascript

Here's my code

```
var isNew = true

function limb(a,b)
{
    if (isNew=true) 
    {
        post(a,b);
        isNew = false;
        post ("first");
    }
    else
    {
        post(a,b);
        post ("not first"); 
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that `else` condition is never triggered. I'm assuming value of `isNew` is never updated, but I have no idea why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some languages `=` is used both to assign values and to compare them. JavaScript uses different operators for each of these.

`x = 10` always means "set `x` to `10`, and give me the value of `x`".
`x == 10` always means "tell me if `x` is equal to `10`".

So your condition could have been `if(isNew == true)` and it would have worked. You can also just put `if(isNew)`.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `if (isNew===true)` to test it.

Comment: Blech, no, it should just be `if (isNew)`.